# Life time of C# Thread that owns WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have an UI thread that creates WPF window and Show it. 
Sample code will be:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => 
    {
        Window window = new Window();
        window.Show();
        Dispatcher.Run();
    });
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

In this code, The main process will create a thread and WPF window will created from the thread. Is the life time of the thread the same as WPF Window? If WPF window closes, will the thread terminates?

Comment: Is it easier to ask it, or just put a breakpoint and check?

Comment: put a [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name.aspx) to the thread and watch the output window.

Answer (score 2):

If you just compile this and try you will find that the thread does not terminate when the window closes.  This is because you start the thread processing a message loop with `Dispatcher.Run()` and this will continue in an infinite loop until you tell it to stop.  The reason for this is that a new WPF application starts with a call to `Application.Run(MyMainWindow)` - in this thread, however, `window` belongs to the thread and `Dispatcher` belongs to the thread, but `Dispatcher` does not belong to `window`, so closing the window does nothing to the dispatcher.

In Winforms you could hack a second UI thread by calling `Application.Run(MyForm)` from within a thread but WPF does not, as far as I know, allow this.  You cannot access `Application.Current` from within a secondary thread and you cannot create and run a new instance of `Application` from within a thread either.  If you really, really, need a second message loop - which I feel is probably not justifiable in any sensible design strategy - you will need to write cleanup code to ensure the thread's Dispatcher shuts down and the thread is terminated.

Comment: 'not justifiable in any sensible design strategy' is the key part of this answer.